# Embedded Linux C interrupt on USB insertion

Tags: c, linux, yocto, mount

I have a small project build with Yocto. When I insert a USB device the kernel prints the info to the console. This tells me something is prompting this and I should be able to capture it in a C program that I write.

My question is, is there a way in a C thread to capture the USB inserted notification, mount, and read a file?

If my application cannot retrieve this notification I can just start a thread and every X seconds run `ls /dev/sda`. If I get a hit then mount and read my file.

Comment: You might want to look into libusb. It provides notifications about plugged USB devices: https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/libusb_hotplug.html

Comment: I saw that. My current issue is I do not have libusb.

Comment: I just added libusb. So I will try this. Thank you

Comment: Something really cool about libusb is that it should not be used for file operations.
Can I use libusb to open a file on an USB storage device?
Yes.
libusb can be used for low-level communication with USB Mass Storage Class devices. But in order to access a file on such a device you must first implement Mass Storage Class, SCSI and the particular file system used on the device, most commonly FAT32.

However, libusb will not do this part for you. In a word, do not use libusb for USB mass storage device.